# Hbitmap Out of memory exception

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks

So I'm trying to make a small program that takes a load of images and makes them into a .gif file.

At the moment it works only if there are a small number of images but after a while memory usage will go above 4gb and I'll get an out of memory exception.

Here is what I have so far. I can't seem to find a way to get rid of the `Hbitmap`

```vb
Public Sub SaveGif()
    TimerGif.Stop()

    Dim stats As FileInfo
    Dim genc As New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder

    For Each img In Directory.GetFiles(txtSaveLocation.Text & "\TMP")
        stats = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(img)
        If stats.Extension = ".bmp" Then
            Dim bitmapImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(img)
            Dim bmp = bitmapImage.GetHbitmap()
            Dim src = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())
            genc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src))
            bitmapImage.Dispose()
        End If
    Next

    Using fs As New FileStream(Path.Combine(txtSaveLocation.Text, "Test.gif"), FileMode.Create)
        genc.Save(fs)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: `GetHbitmap` creates a bitmap, not just returns a handle. You're [supposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.gethbitmap?view=netframework-4.8) to delete it with `DeleteObject`.

Comment: So I've added `<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function DeleteObject(hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function` and called DeleteObject after disposing of the bitmap image but I still keep getting Out of memory exception on the same line

Comment: Just a side note; you can get rid of a few lines of code with `For Each img As String In Directory.GetFiles(txtSaveLocation.Text & "\TMP", "*.bmp")`